# Notepad++ Replacing multiple text and texts in all rows with multiple texts

Tags: regex, notepad++, textwrangler

I have a big txt file. See example below;

```
||0011||
||0011||
||0011||
||0011||
||0011||
||0011||
||0011||
||0011||
||0011||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0122||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
||0232||
```

What i want to do is, i want to replace 0011 with 001112, 0122 with 012234, 0232 with 023213. My problem is, that i want to replace them in one go. I am aware of replacing them in three steps i.e, first i can replace all rows that have 0011 with 001112, similar second time i can replace rows that have 0122 with 012234 etc. Please keep in mind that there are more columns and rows in the file. Above is just an example.

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Yes bro. I can't seem to find answer to my question. Can you help?

Comment: Well, 'bro', look at the following link: http://bit.ly/1vTr3hI

Comment: What is the logic here of conversion

Comment: I went through the link you provided. But i am unable to solve my problem. Could you take a minute and write the exact code needed to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't do a conditional replacement with notepad++, you can use this way:

1) add these three lines at the end of your file:

```
#001112
#012234
#023213
```

2) use this pattern and replacement:

```
pattern: \|\|\K(\d+)(?=\|\|[\s\S]+#\1(\d+))|(?:\r?\n#.*)+$
replace: $1$2
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tC5lF8/3)